# Make django admin to display no more than 100 characters in list results

Tags: python, django

I am using Django admin for my site and I would like to make a customization on how a field is displayed on the list_display page for one of my models.

One of my models has a `TextField` that can be 300 characters

When the model is listed in the Django admin, I would like to limit the length of the text displayed in the Admin list display to 100 characters.

Is there a way to do this within the Django Admin class?

admin.py:

```
class ApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Application
    list_display = [ "title1", "title2"]
```

models.py:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    title1 = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    title2 = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can display a property that returns a truncated version of your field's value in your ModelAdmin class. Leveraging the built-in template filters makes this easy.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars  # or truncatewords

class Foo(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()

    @property
    def short_description(self):
        return truncatechars(self.description, 100)

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['short_description']
```

Comment: Is there any way that i can pass arguments like 100 in the list display

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Brandon , actually i want that i define that truncate function only once in the parent class and i can then pass the argument and words in the listdisplay so that i don't need to define that function in every model

Comment: You won't be able to do that using the list_display property. You'll have to apply the filter to each field.

Comment: I would like to mention, that if somebody don't want to add a view related method to his model class he can also add a method to the admin class. This callable will get passed the model object as argument. I think this way is better then the above solution. Imagine you would need the string truncated to different sizes in different admins, then you would end with methods like short_xxx, veryshort_xxx , ... in your model class.

Comment: @tobltobs  Can you provide an example on how to do the same in admin model? I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: @Stryker, its pretty simple.  Define a method in your admin class that takes an object instance as its only argument. It should return a string.  Then use that method name in your list_display tuple, without quotes.

Comment: Adding custom properties to ModelAdmin is described here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: and how to define verbose_name?

Answer (score 3):

In Your Admin.py File :

```
class ApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['titl1','title2'] # titl1 is behalf of title1
    
    def titl1(self, obj):
        return obj.title1[:100]
```