# Creating a Django Property

Tags: python, django, django-models

I copied this piece of code from another SO question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285740/make-django-admin-to-display-no-more-than-100-characters-in-list-results)).

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars  # or truncatewords

class Foo(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()

    @property
    def short_description(self):
        return truncatechars(self.description, 100)

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['short_description']
```

I also copied this piece of code from this question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017523/populate-month-based-on-date-field-in-django)).

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False) 
    Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    Month = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)   

        def get_month(self):
            if self.Date:
                self.Month = self.Date.strftime("%B")
                self.save()
```

I am aware of the concepts being discussed in these 2 questions, however I am not sure where I can find the list of available options. For example, the use of `return truncatechars(self.description, 100)` and the use of `self.Month = self.Date.strftime("%B")`, where is the library where I can find my available options? I want to create a new property but not sure where to find my 'library' of options.

I also assume this will always be made in the `models.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what you mean by `'library' of options`, there is no library for defining a property in Django. It is just a normal [attribute of Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) since version 2.2.

and yes, models.py is the place where you define it since only there you define the fields of a class.

[**> example for property from official docs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. And thank you for providing the links.